# How to rescale the intensity range of a grayscale 3 dimension image (x,y,z) using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, 3d

I can't find information online about the intensity rescaling of a 3D image made of several 2D images.

I'm looking for the same function as `imadjust` which only works for 2D images.

My 3D image is the combination of 2D images stacked together but I have to process the 3D image and not the 2D images one by one.

I can't loop imadjust because I want to process the images as one, to consider all the information available, in all directions.

Comment: Check the edit.. Does my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes I saw your edit, I changed one or two sentences. I couldn't find the function to edit my question straight from your suggestion... Because I guess it does make you earn reputation ?

Comment: Haha! Actually i was referring to the edit to my answer.. does it work for you? have you tried that?

Comment: Try the new edit.. also see to that dimensions of all the images are all same (atleast the number of rows)

Comment: I managed to concatenate all the images together because I see it from the size variable but I don't have enough memory to imadjust this new variable... I guess we need twice the RAM of the array to apply the function, once to treat the information and once to write it... ?   Maximum possible array:     12410 MB (1.301e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     12410 MB (1.301e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:     16452 MB (1.725e+10 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):     16289 MB (1.708e+10 bytes)

Comment: As i guessed it earlier, thats a huge amount of data. May be post it as a new question with the code you already have with tags 'memory', 'performance etc'. That might attract many users who have the potential to find an alternate solution for this problem. good luck :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For applying `imadjust` for set of 2D grayscale images taking the whole value into account, this trick might work

```
a = imread('pout.tif');  
a = imresize(a,[256 256]);   %// re-sizing to match image b's dimension
b = imread('cameraman.tif');

Im = cat(3,a,b);     
%//where a,b are separate grayscale images of same dimensions
%// if you have the images separately you could edit this line to
%// Im = cat(2,a,b);
%// and also avoid the next step

%// reshaping into a 2D matrix to apply imadjust
Im = reshape(Im,size(Im,1),[]);

out = imadjust(Im);     %// applying imadjust

%// finally reshaping back to its original shape
out = reshape(out,size(a,1),size(a,2),[]);
```

**To check:**

```
x = out(:,:,1);
y = out(:,:,2);
```

As you could see from the Workspace image, the first image (variable `x`) is not re-scaled to `0-255` as its previous range (variable `a`) was not near the 0 point.

**WorkSpace:**

[image]

---

**Edit:** You could do this as a one-step process like this: (as the other answer suggests)

```
%// reshaping to single column using colon operator and then using imadjust
%// then reshaping it back
out = reshape(imadjust(Image3D(:)),size(Image3D));
```

**Edit2:**

As you have image as cell arrays in `I2`, try this:

```
I2D = cat(2,I2{:})
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, by 3D I mean 3 dimensions (x,y,z) , not RGB. I have a grayscale 3 dimensions image.

Comment: @Sarahdata i don't get it,, u mean you have a bunch of grayscale images stacked together to form a 3D matrix? why don't you loop it over?

Comment: That's right, I have 2D images concatenate together to form a 3D image. I can't loop imadjust because I want to process the images as one, to consider all the information available, in all directions. What do you think ?

Comment: @Sarahdata thats a good question.. you probably have to edit your question to make that clear.. also see the edit, if that works for you

Comment: When you write `out = reshape(out,size(a,1),size(a,1),[]);`, what does `size(a,1)` mean ? That the first and second dimension whould = the number of row of `a` ?

Comment: @Sarahdata, `size(a,1)` gives the number of rows, similarly `size(a,2)` gives number of columns. NO. first dimension = number of rows of `a` while 2nd dimension = sum of number of columns of each 2D grayscale images (as they were concatenated next to each other. )

Comment: OKay, I didn't get that `size` was a function, I thought it was an argument of the reshape function. Than, for the reshape of the 2D matrix in 3D, it should be `reshape(out, size(a,1), size(a,2),[]` and not `reshape(out, size(a,1), size(a,1),[]`   isn't it ? It doen't matter here because nrow=ncol but still...

Comment: @Sarahdata, Nice catch.. yeah.. u are rite.. i tested with square images.. so didn't get any strange results.. i'm editing my answer now :) thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Hi, so your idea perfectly worked on my sample data set (33 images) but know that I want to threat my whole data set (2249 images of 1984 x 1984 pixels), its says in the work space that there is "Too many elements" for the Ì2D`variable and the code stops at the `cat` step for inconsistant dimension.  All my images are `unit8`. Any idea how to skip the problem ?                          `I2D=I2{1};
for k=2:o
    I2D=cat(2,I2D,I2{k});
end
I2D=imadjust(I2D);`

Comment: @Sarahdata have you tried the alternate answer added as 'edit'?

Comment: before using the `reshape` function I should first concatenate all the images, I remind you that I initially have 2D images. I'll have somehow to put them all together to get all the information I want.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this for 3D image is to treat the data as a vector and then reshape back.

Something like this:

```
%create a random 3D image.
x = rand(10,20,30);

%adjust intensity range
x_adj = imadjust( x(:), size(x) );
```